# Planning a project on per-week basis

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I usually plan actions needed to complete a project on per-week basis. So, for a project that's supposed to take 3 weeks, I might have:

```
* My Project:
  * TODO Week1 [0/2]
    SCHEDULED: <Sun 09.08.2015 w31>
    - [ ] First task  
    - [ ] Second task
  * TODO Week2 [0/2] ...
    SCHEDULED: <Sun 16.08.2015 w32>
    - [ ] Third task  
    - [ ] Fourth task
  * TODO Week3 [0/0] ...
```

Please note that I am using `<%a %d.%m.%Y w%W>` as the custom date format.

**Questions:**

1. Although I have `(setq calendar-week-start-day 0)` in `init.el`, if I press `Shift-right` on a date that is Sunday, the week number changes. That is, Sunday and Monday are on different weeks of the year. Can I cause the week to start on Sunday?
2. I am looking for an easy way to build a sparse tree showing headlines  relevant to a certain week. So far, the only way I found is to build the tree based on a date range, which is a lot of key strokes. Is there a way to do this easier, e.g. build a sparse tree based on the week number? I tried looking for the regular expression `w31`, but that did not succeed, because `w31` is only displayed, but is not part of the file content...
3. All my projects have a similar structure -- headlines of the form:

   ```
   TODO Week x [/] 
   SCHEDULED: <Sun ...>
   ```

   Is there a way to generate this structure easier than typing each headline?